# mySQL: Filter on a column with CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case, where-clause

I have the following code:

```
    SELECT
    t1.a
    t1.b
    CASE WHEN t1.c = Z THEN m
         WHEN t1.c = Y THEN n
         ELSE p END as m_or_n_or_p
    FROM t1
```

Can I add

```
WHERE m_or_n_or_p = m
```

at the end and in this way filter my query or do I have to wrap it all in another SELECT?

Comment: _...Can I add..._ Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: Yes, you can add a filter like that.  However, as @B001 stated, you should try to do a few things before just posting a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL doesn't allow using aliases in the `where` clause. If you don't want to wrap the query in an additional query, you could always replicate the expression from the select list to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT t1.a
       t1.b
       CASE WHEN t1.c = Z THEN m
            WHEN t1.c = Y THEN n
            ELSE p
       END as m_or_n_or_p
FROM t1
WHERE  CASE WHEN t1.c = Z THEN m
            WHEN t1.c = Y THEN n
            ELSE p
       END = m
```

Comment: I tried to use it with more than one WHERE... and there was an error. any idea ?? example : `SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE t1.a = C OR CASE WHEN ... END = m` . @Mureinik , any help please ?

Comment: @mlwn I'm not sure I understand. Can you post a new question with all the information and link it here?

Comment: it was a typing error.. i figured it out later.. and i had to enclose each `(CASE ... END)` in parentheses.. thank you for your answer.. works perfectly...